# Issue building Grails project with Maven

Tags: grails, maven, grails-maven

I'm creating a "Mavenised" Grails project but am having trouble running the maven install goal on the project.

To create the project I've used the following archetype: `grails-maven-archetype`

It has built my project structure correctly and set up all the necessary configuration files (pom.xml etc)

However, when I run mvn install on this I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.206s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 15 10:40:15 GMT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 65M/366M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.0.1:maven-test (default) on project MyApp: Unable to start Grails: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: Native Library C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\jline_.dll already loaded in another classloader -> [Help 1]
```

However when I run the grails goals that this is trying to run individually e.g. `mvn grails:maven-compile` they work and I am able to fully build the project.

I am guessing when running mvn install the process is locking the jline_.dll and not releasing it before trying to read it in again in the next goal.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Any advice on how to get around this?

I really need mvn install to build the project correctly so I can set up effective build scripts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2.0.1 version doesn't work on Windows machines. Known issue. Sorry about that, you will need to wait for 2.0.2

Comment: Was worried this was the case :( Thanks for response..
Does it work in Linux?